# Rails : How to get parallels running with Pow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parallels, rack-pow

I've recently starting using [Pow](http://pow.cx/) for local Rails application development. I typically use parallels 7 for cross-browser testing. I'm running into an issue where my POW development url - e.g. somesubdomain.domain.dev - is not accessible from the parallels virtual machines.

Has anyone had any luck setting up a pow + parallels combination? Suggestions?

Comment: There is an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379453/remotely-viewing-web-pages-served-by-pow-cx

Answer (score 1):

Adding my experience to this question even though it is was asked a few months ago. I had a similar problem recently, and although I was never successful accessing my pow url from the windows machine I followed the instructions here and was able to connect to the local app from  parallels:

http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/testing_a_rails_application_in_ie_in_parallels_and_in_leopard/

The post was written for Snow Leopard but I had success using Lion too.

Answer (score 1):

As someone answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379453/remotely-viewing-web-pages-served-by-pow-cx), http://xip.io/ makes this super easy to do.

Comment: Although this solution does work, it is not an answer for the question posed above. This is a common solution that has the disadvantage of requiring an internet connection for your development environment to function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I manage to install the gem powder, who allow me to stop and start pow.
https://github.com/Rodreegez/powder

For cross-browser testing, I'm launching the rails server on localhost:3000.

I would like to have a better solution too :-)

Anyone ?