# Pow and VMware Fusion

Tags: vmware-fusion, rack-pow

I am using Pow to serve a Rack application on Mac OS X. `http://myapp.dev` correctly displays the application. On the same machine I am using VMware Fusion to run Windows 7 while sharing the Mac's network connection. I would like to test the Rack application using Internet Explorer within the VM. `http://vmnet8.adapter.ip.address` correctly displays the "Pow is installed screen". However, `htttp://myapp.dev` no longer works.

I understand that Pow creates a DNS resolver and uses it's own DNS server to intercept domains ending in ".dev" and redirect them to localhost. Is it possible to get this to work within the VM also?

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379453/remotely-viewing-web-pages-served-by-pow-cx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a symlink in your `~/.pow` directory called `default`, and point it to the app you would like to test in VMWare.  `http://vmnet8.adapter.ip.address` will now use that app instead of presenting the default pow screen, as will `http://<myhostname>.local`.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I uses virtualbox, but it looks like it is kind the same concern I had to deal with, so:

- Get the IP used by your Mac with ifconfig or any other way you prefer. In this case lets assume the IP address is 10.249.158.68
- This link explains how to execute POW server from other computer; in our case it will be the virtualized Windows image: http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.1.5

So open IE[7|8|9] on your Windows virtual machine and type:
http://myapp.10.249.158.68.xip.io/ ---> replaces "myapp" to the name used in your Mac to refer your project